# Как поймать asp.net mvc controller exception?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, исключения, asp.net-web-api

Есть метод контроллера

```
[DeflateCompression]
[Route("Current/{count}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCurrent(int count)
    {
        return someting here
    }
```

И он никогда не вызывается. 
Своя реализация ExceptionFilterAttribute прицеплена к контроллеру, но не вызывается. 
Клиент получает 500 ошибку без деталей. 
Другие контроллеры вызываются без ошибок.

Как поймать exception?

UPD: добавил код упоминаемого фильтра

```
public class LoggingExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{

    public LoggingExceptionFilterAttribute(){}

       public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var trackingId = context.Request.Headers.Contains(HeaderNames.TrackingHeader) ?
            context.Request.Headers.GetValues(HeaderNames.TrackingHeader).First() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        if (context.Exception is NotImplementedException)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                ErrorResponse.Create(context.Exception, trackingId));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "Внутренности" кастомного атрибута можно посмотреть?

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: LoggingExceptionFilterAttribute это и есть DeflateCompression? Если да, то весь код OnException-метода в try зверните, и попробуйте посмотреть что там за исключение выскакивает. Если там не будет исключений - сообщите, будем дальше думать =)